# dynamically named singleton properties across instances in python

Tags: python, oop, dynamic, factory

```
class Factory:
    def get_singleton(self, class_name):
        if class_name not in Factory.__dict__:
            new_instance = self.get_new_instance(class_name)
            new_attribute = self.get_attribute_name_from_class_name(class_name)
            Factory.__setattr__(Factory, new_attribute, new_instance)
            return Factory.__getattribute__(new_attribute)
```

I am making a object factory class and in my get_singleton function above, i have this line:

```
Factory.__setattr__(Factory, new_attribute, new_instance)
```

The docs say that **setattr** wants a instance for the first parameter, but i would like to be able to set up dynamically named properties across instances. That way the next time i call the get_singleton function, it will return the same class instance i created on previous calls. I want to be able to make dynamically named singleton properties across instances.

Here is how i call this function from the outside:

```
manager = Factory().get_singleton('Manager')
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured out my own answer. By using settattr i am able to dynamically create non instance attributes. Here is the code.

```
class Factory:
    @staticmethod
    def get_singleton(class_name):
        new_attribute = Factory.get_attribute_name_from_class_name(class_name)
        if new_attribute not in Factory.__dict__:
            new_instance = Factory.get_new_instance(class_name)
            setattr(Factory, new_attribute, new_instance)
        return Factory.__dict__[new_attribute]
```